# Drum machine circuit diagram

Tags: signal, components, diagram

[image: Schematic 1]

[image: Drum machine circuit Diagram]

I'm having trouble understanding this circuit. Can someone help me get through it? I'm trying to understand what the signal is doing from start to end but keep running into electrical deadlocks.

Comment: The schematic is drawn in a strange fashion (the drawing style itself).  I wonder if it was reverse-engineered from a PCB.

Comment: I am working on a memoir in which I am talking about the Drum Machine! So i did all the history, the protagonist brands on the market today, and i thought it will be a good idea to build my own drum machine. looked on the internet for some ideas and found the Bleep Drum by Dr. Bleep. Great! so i bought one, built one with the easy instructions they have on there website, but i really want to explain how everything works. So this diagram was downloaded straight from his websit

Comment: Here is a list of the bleep drum's components: 1x Cicruit imprimé sur carte
1x Arduino Atmega328P chip
1x MCP4901 IC chip
1x Prise DIP 28 broches
1x Prise DIP 8 broches
1x Resonator de 16MHz
1x Transistor 78I05
2x Potentiometre 10K
4x Boutons 12mm Bleu, Rouge, Jaune et Vert
4x Boutons 6mm noir
1x Capacitor 10uF
2x capacitor 220uF
5x Resistor 1k
1x RGB LED
1x Jack stéréo (1/8)
1x interupteur SPDT
1x Batterie 9V

Comment: I added a better circuit

Comment: It is a simple sound generator with ATMega microcontroller and external digital-to-analog converter attached through SPI. It has sound samples stored in the MCU's flash memory. The buttons are triggers from individual instruments. When they close, the MCU starts playing the samples by sending data to the DAC, which converts them to analog sound waveform.

Comment: What is an "electrical deadlock"?

Comment: Thank you very much, i really appreciate  it. 
En electrical deadlock is just a term i used to say I lost the signal, couldnt know what to do with it, just a small joke

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can make out

[image]

and

[image]

Looks like an 8 pin job of some description.

Comment: Now I've seen the extra comment the DAC is the MCP4901 - see http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22248a.pdf

Comment: @AkselTengirsek If this answer helped you to solve your problem, then please choose it as accepted answer. Thanks